# Extracting elements from text file with PYTHON

Tags: python, txt

I have just imported the word file and read it as text. In that word, there were some tables with the names (table 1, table2, table, etc) with the relevant info respectively.
How I can iterate over that text file and extract info between words table 1 and table2 let's say and assign it to a string or list?
Sorry for hiding the information on the table, as I do not have the right to share this file.

The main purpose of the task is automation. I should write the script that each time the word format is uploaded, there are column names(in that word) and in front of the column name, particular information should be extracted and added to the particular columns of the database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem solvable by regex.

```py
import re 

your_input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur Table 1 sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy Table 2 eirmod tempor Table 3 invidunt ut labore Table 4 et dolore magna'
resulting_list = re.split(r'\s*Table \d+\s*', your_input)
print(resulting_list)

# output
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur', 'sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy', 'eirmod tempor', 'invidunt ut labore', 'et dolore magna']
```

It just uses `table n` as token to split at. `\s*` removes trailing spaces. Result is a list. The token is case sensitive in this example.

Comment: Thank you very much. The main point is that I am receiving file as word and have to convert it txt, as did in my script. then I have have to get rid of "\n" which I did as well. The point is I do not know how to save it, for implementing the script you mentioned.

Comment: For saving you can use vanilla io `f = open('your_file.txt', 'w')` (`your_file.txt` will be created if it doesn't exist otherwise it will be overwritten. To append you need `a` instead of `w` as 2nd parameter) and write each elemnt of the list as a single line with `f.write('\n'.join(your_text))`. Further reading here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question

My txt file looks like this:

```
table1
Hello World!
I am here
table2
```

and then I use read to get the hole content and split the string with the keywords

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
text = file.read()
result = text.split('table1')[1].split('table2')
print(result[0])
```

the result looks like

```
Hello World!
I am here
```

It is not as smooth as regex, but maybe more easy to understand :)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!)  The problem is that i have to read word file first. Afterwards I can convert it to txt and save (do not know how to save so just printed after the looping and  getting rid of the "\n")